# Get single array value

Tags: php, arrays

Here's why i use print_r

```
preg_match($regexpattern, $string, $matches);
$array = print_r($matches);
```

and this will result the array like below
i have try to get the array result without printing it, but its doesnt work

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://example.com/page-1
)
```

Question, how to get the $array in single value like:

`echo $array['0'];` and will show result like this `https://example.com/page-1`

Thank you

Comment: `echo $array['0'];`

Comment: Technically `$array[0]`. Use numerical indexes, not strings, for linear arrays. Associative arrays are slightly different and use string keys.

Comment: `echo $array[0];`

Comment: its still echoing the whole array @splash58

Comment: echo can't show whole array. It will write - `Array`

Comment: `echo current($array)`

Comment: share what `print_r( $array)` is ?

Comment: sorry, im updating my question bove

Comment: @anabelle I still don't understand the problem - https://eval.in/921755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Understand What You wants to say

use foreach loop insted of print_r()

```
<?php

$array = array("https://example.com/page-1");

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
echo "<hr>";
echo $array [0];

?>
```

Also check [Result Here.](https://eval.in/921743)

Comment: should it work if i use $Array = print_r($array);
echo $Array[0]; ? because i keep getting the whole array result

Comment: for more see my answer. there is no need of  print_r.whole array is print because you use `print_r`.and also if you use print_r it works.

Comment: im updating my question above

Comment: Your answer is working but seems i get problem with the other function so make this doesnt work. thanks anyway

Comment: Update question With That Function. i may help you